# Leaving Arduino Kit in the car, in summer (40+~), do i need to tell the customers?

Tags: arduino, components, temperature, damage

Arduino kits containing the following, stored in a plastic box:

- Sensors
- Male to male wires
- The actual arduino board
- other usual components such as resistors etc...

Leaving it in the sun for a day or two in a car, where temperature outside is 40c~, would it do any damage? is it necessarily to tell customers that the kits were stored or forgotten in such an environment?

Comment: The surface temp can easily rise 20'C above outside temp. Depending plastic used, this is within 65'C storage temps so should be ok. components are rated much higher, but plastic cases can warp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *operating* temperature of the main processor is -40C to 85C.  The *storage* temperature may be larger. I'd expect all the other components to have similar temperature ranges.

Usually you can find this information in data sheets under a section labeled "Absolute Maximum Ratings" which reflects the conditions where correct operation may not be gauranteed, but permanent damage should not result.  In the Atmega328p data sheet we find the following absolute maximum temperature conditions:

- Operating Temperature. . . . . . . . . . . -55°C to +125°C
- Storage Temperature . . . . . . . . . . . . -65°C to +150°C

On this data sheet this section includes the following note (since every manufacturer defines "absolute maximum" differently it's important to pay attention to these):

> *NOTICE: Stresses beyond those listed under “Absolute
>   Maximum Ratings” may cause permanent damage
>   to the device. This is a stress rating only
>   and functional operation of the device at these
>   or other conditions beyond those indicated in
>   the operational sections of this specification is
>   not implied. Exposure to absolute maximum rating
>   conditions for extended periods may affect
>   device reliability.

As such, there is no reason to expect any consequence to storing it in a hot car, and thus no reason to share your storage methods with your customers.

Answer (score 1):

Switched-off electronics is usually fine with moderate heat, so long as it's dry. May be a problem in a very humid environment, as it would cause condensation when cooled down.

The big exception is batteries, which should not be taken over 60C.